# For a given database is dbo.sysobjects a partition of the master system database?

Tags: sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000 I noticed that the `sysbojects` exists in each database. Is this and other system tables in each non system database a partition of the `master` `sysobjects` table as well as the other system tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a partition of the `master..sysobjects` table. You'll notice that if you create a table in a user database:

```
USE whatever;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.floob(splunge INT);
GO
```

That table shows up in `whatever..sysobjects`, but not in `master..sysobjects`.

Why are you learning about SQL Server 2000 metadata now? A little late to the party, no? :-)

Comment: Aaron, I was working on partitioning some tables by year and then thought that the system tables might also be partitioned.  Just curious.

Comment: How are you partitioning in SQL Server 2000? Partitioning wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2005. :-)

Comment: Oh.  Well its learning I guess the video I was using was for sql 2008. thx